# On Ubuntu 20.04, downgrade the Subversion from default 1.13.0 to 1.9.3 (which was default in Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: svn, ubuntu-20.04

On Ubuntu 20.04, if you install the subversion using standard apt-get then by default subversion 1.13.0 will be installed.

So how to downgrade the subversion in Ubuntu 20.04 to 1.9.3 ?

Comment: Why do you want to downgrade on old version?

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade the Subversion present in Ubuntu 20.04 to 1.9.3 by following below steps

1. Install the Subversion **if it's already not installed** by following command on command prompt:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install subversion
   ```

   Above command will install the **subversion** **1.13.0** with required dependencies. If subersion 1.13.0 is already installed then you should skip this step.
2. Now remove **libsvn1** using following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove libsvn1
   ```

   Above command will remove the **libsvn1** as well as the **subversion** keeping rest of the dependencies installed as it is.
3. Download **.deb** for **subversion** 1.9.3 from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/subversion/1.9.3-2ubuntu1.3 and download **libsvn1** from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libsvn1/1.9.3-2ubuntu1.3 in some folder.
4. Go to the folder where **.deb** files are downloaded in command prompt and run following command

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i subversion_1.9.3-2ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb libsvn1_1.9.3-2ubuntu1.3_amd64.deb
   ```

Above command will install the **subversion** **1.9.3**

5. You can check the installed version of **subvesion** using following command

   ```
   svn --version
   ```

Thanks

Comment: the link to download are blocked by browser